# Android: Database handler SQLiteException

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Hello all i have this method in the database handler class and what this class do is to return the ID of the product from the product table. However, i am receiving this sqliteexception which i do not know why.
Please advice thank you.

```
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCT = "product"
    private static final String KEY_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

public String getProductId(String productName) {
   String selectQuery = "SELECT productid FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT+ " WHERE " +KEY_PRODUCTNAME +" = " + productName;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    String productid = cursor.toString();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return productid;
}
```

Errors:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1884): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1884): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "Bluedress34.50" (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT productid FROM product WHERE productname = "Bluedress34.50"
```

my activity class:

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

                    String productname = pname.getText().toString();
                    String productQTY = pqty.getText().toString();

                    String productnameid = db.getUProductId(productname);


                    JSONObject json = userFunction.addSales(productnameid, productQty);

}

}
```

my userfunction class:

```
public JSONObject addSales(productnameid, productQty){
    // Building Parameters

    List<NameValuePair> paramsfile = new ArrayList();

    paramsfile.add(new BasicNameValuePair("productnameid", productnameid));
    paramsfile.add(new BasicNameValuePair("productQty", productQty));


    JSONObject jsonfileName  =  jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(addFileURL, paramsfile);

   Log.e("JSON", jsonfileName.toString());
    return jsonfileName;
}
```

Comment: **1:** How comes that you have `KEY_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";` and your sql string produces `SELECT productid FROM product WHERE uid = "Bluedress34.50"`? So, I assume that you changed to `KEY_PRODUCTNAME = "uid";` **2:** Is this `"Bluedress34.50"` correct (is this the value in 1 field)? Because it really seems the concatenation of 2 field values...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since product name is in String Format use `'` in query, like below,

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT productid FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT 
      + " WHERE " + KEY_PRODUCTNAME +" ='" + productName  +"'";
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! i am now not facing the error. But i have another question to consult you. I am getting the productid however when i try to get the productid from the activity class, it is always 0. i have added the codes used in my activity above.

Comment: @user3306996, can you upload more code ? Because Using this code, you should get proper result. I think problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @user3306996, `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);` after this line write `cursor.moveToFirst();` and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, then may be problem is here `String productname = pname.getText().toString();
                    String productQTY = pname.getText().toString();` why these two variables using same EditText's value ? Should they use different EditText's value ?

Comment: my mistake!! i have corrected it but still the value obtained is 0

Comment: Ok, can you send me your code by email ? my email is there in my profile.

Comment: if the code is fine above could the problem lies with the api i am using?

Comment: @user3306996, I dont think so It may be possible that there is some little code error. If I check the whole code then only I can solve it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather write it so:

```
String selectQuery =
    "SELECT productid FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT+ " WHERE " + KEY_PRODUCTNAME + " =  ?";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{productName});
```

Comment: This is good, just fix the string array constructor syntax `new String[] { productName }`

Answer (score 1):

Any string value in database transactions should be accessed in `'` single quote only.

Just write your product value in single quote `'` as below:
**" = '" + productName +"'";**

Query:

```
"SELECT productid FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT+ " WHERE " +KEY_PRODUCTNAME +" = '" + productName +"'";
```

Answer (score 1):

it just a simple mistake. you forgot to add single qoute like below:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT productid FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT+ " WHERE " +KEY_PRODUCTNAME +" = '" + productName +"'";
```