# getting android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException in Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to take date, time & title field value for creating reminder. I don't know how to store date & time data. I'm not able to insert data into database. Advance thanks for help.

AddReminder.java

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class AddReminder extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private EditText et_name, et_date, et_time, et_reminder_title;
    private Button btn_add, btn_view, btn_date, btn_time, btn_set_reminder, btn_view_reminders;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute;

    private String s_date, s_time, s_title;

    private DBOperation operation;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_reminder);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Add RemindMe");

        operation = new DBOperation(this);


        /*********************************************************************/

        btn_date = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
        btn_time = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
        et_date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_date);
        et_time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.in_time);
        et_reminder_title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_reminder_title);

        btn_date.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_time.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_set_reminder = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_set_reminder);
        btn_set_reminder.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_view_reminders = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_view_reminders);
        btn_view_reminders.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == btn_date) {

            // Get Current Date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            et_date.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
        if (v == btn_time) {

            // Get Current Time
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Launch Time Picker Dialog
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                              int minute) {

                            et_time.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }

        if(v == btn_set_reminder){

            boolean isInserted = operation.insertData(et_date.getText().toString(),
                    et_time.getText().toString(),
                    et_reminder_title.getText().toString());

            if (isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(AddReminder.this, "Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (v == btn_view_reminders)
        {

            Cursor res = operation.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 00)
            {
                showMsg("ERROR", "No Data Found");
                return;
            }
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext())
            {
                buffer.append("ID: "+res.getString(0) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Date: "+res.getString(1) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Time: "+res.getString(2) + "\n");
                buffer.append("Title: "+res.getString(3) + "\n\n");
            }

            showMsg("Data", buffer.toString());
        }
    }

    public void showMsg(String msg_title, String msg)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(msg_title);
        builder.setMessage(msg);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

DBOperation.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DBOperation extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "reminder_db.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "reminder_table";
    public static final String ID = "C_ID";
    public static final String DATE = "C_DATE";
    public static final String TIME = "C_TIME";
    public static final String TITLE = "C_TITLE";

    public DBOperation(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + "(C_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, C_DATE TEXT, C_NAME TEXT, C_TITLE TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String date, String time, String title){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(DATE,date);
        contentValues.put(TIME,time);
        contentValues.put(TITLE,title);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }    
}
```

Error

```
Error inserting C_DATE=8/3/2017 C_TIME=23:14 C_TITLE=Rem
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table reminder_table has no column named C_TIME (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO reminder_table(C_DATE,C_TIME,C_TITLE) VALUES (?,?,?)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
     at mukesh.com.task11.DBOperation.insertData(DBOperation.java:44)
     at mukesh.com.task11.AddReminder.onClick(AddReminder.java:146)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can't read explicit error messages, can't search on Google, ... Oh boy, are you sure you should be working in this field ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Database handler SQLiteException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22832330/android-database-handler-sqliteexception)

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't have the column `C_TIME` in your onCreate script:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + "(C_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, C_DATE TEXT, C_NAME TEXT, C_TITLE TEXT)");
}
```

You forgot to add the field:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + "(C_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, C_DATE TEXT, C_NAME TEXT, C_TITLE TEXT, C_TIME TEXT)");
}
```